# API Росфинмониторинг

Tags: php, api, интеграция

Всем привет. Вопрос такой...
Кто либо делал интеграцию со службой росфинмониторинг https://portal.fedsfm.ru ?
Я изучил всю их документацию, отправил кучу запросов в тех.поддержку, перерыл весь интернет, но результата нет ни какого абсолютно. Как я понял из статей, которые нарыл на просторах интернета, они работают по протоколу SOAP но у них нет схемы WSDL. Нет также примеров xml для получения токена и работы с методами. Если кто-то уже делал что-то подобное опишите пожалуйста весь этот процесс. Это уже крик души...

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но возможно речь идет о Системе межведомственного электронного взаимодействия (СМЭВ), в ней есть вид сведений  ЕИС Росфинмониторинга (мнемоника FSFM01)
https://smev3.gosuslugi.ru/ , но туда не у всех есть доступ

Answer (score 0):

В личном кабинете есть подробная инструкция "Руководство пользователя электронного сервиса ''Сервисный концентратор Росфинмониторинга'' для КО" для взаимодействия посредством REST-запросов.